# PHP Coding Techniques, Is it Necessary/Proper Coding Technique to create variables prior to using them

Tags: php, phpstorm

I've been trying out PhpStorm and it seems like a good IDE. I've noticed that I get these warning on the side of the code window telling me that a variable may not have been defined.

Basic Example

```
if (some logic here) {

    $getStatus_SQL = 'SELECT status_ID, status_Name FROM myTable';
    $getStatus_RS = $db_con->query($getStatus_SQL);
    $statusOption = ''; <----------- Variable Defined Here -------------<

    while ($status = $getStatus_RS->fetch_assoc()){
        $statusName = $status['status_Name'];
        if ($statusName == $taskStatus){
            $statusOption .= '<option selected value="'.$status['status_ID'].'">'.$status['status_Name'].'</option>';
        } else {
            $statusOption .= '<option value="'.$status['status_ID'].'">'.$status['status_Name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
}
```

Now I echo `$statusOption` variable in HTML, and this is where I get the warning saying:

> Variable $statusOption may have not been defined

However if I define the variable outside the "If statement" the warning goes away.

Example

```
$statusOption = NULL;

if (some logic here) {

    $getStatus_SQL = 'SELECT status_ID, status_Name FROM myTable';
    $getStatus_RS = $db_con->query($getStatus_SQL);

    while ($status = $getStatus_RS->fetch_assoc()){
        $statusName = $status['status_Name'];
        if ($statusName == $taskStatus){
            $statusOption .= '<option selected value="'.$status['status_ID'].'">'.$status['status_Name'].'</option>';
        } else {
            $statusOption .= '<option value="'.$status['status_ID'].'">'.$status['status_Name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
}
```

So my Question is

Is it proper coding technique to define variable before you use them in `if` or `while` statements?

Comment: Yes, it is proper to instantiate your variables prior to using them as it reduces the chance of getting "Notice: undefined" messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, it is not necessary to define variables or object properties before you use them. Use of an undefined variable will imply a value of `null`. This will result in a `E_NOTICE` level log message, or if you are trying to request a method on an undefined object it will be `E_ERROR` and execution will stop.

However, it is **very good practice to ensure variables are always defined** in your code. In PHP, this means not first assigning them inside of conditional statements and, declaring object properties in the class definition.

The reason for this is that it ensures the variable is always set to a controlled value. Future edits to the code will be easier when the original programmers intentions are clearly defined in the code and are less likely to result in unexpected behavior. If for example, another variable with the same name is declared or the condition that sets the variable is removed. In worst cases, lack of declaring variables could represent a security risk.

Comment: Great info exactly what is was looking for, going to check mark this one as the answer Thanks Steve.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that warning in PHPStorm because there is a code path that can cause the variable to not be defined.

In your case, you have (simplified):

```
while ($getStatus_RS->fetch_assoc()){
    $statusOption = 'something';
}
```

In this case, the code path that can cause the variable to remain undefined is if `$getStatus_RS->fetch_assoc()` returns a false-y value. In this case, whatever is inside your `while` block will not execute, and `$statusOption` will never be defined.

A different way to look at it would be:

```
if (rand(0,10) > 5) {
    $foo = 'bar';
}
echo $foo;
```

PHPStorm will give the same warning here, because in approximately half of the cases, `$foo` will not have been defined.

Defining the variable outside of the loop so that it always has a value is just one way of resolving the warning. Others can be things like throwing an exception if your query doesn't give a valid result, or wrapping your HTML in an `if(isset($statusOption))` block, or similar.

Comment: Thanks for that, i can see how the variable would remain undefined and how it might just be relevant to phpstorm. It brings an issue that i have not thought of before trying out PHPStorm in regards to coding techniques.